# c++ custom textual code input parser

Tags: c++, parsing, graph, matrix

I need to write a graph file parser (the graph is generated by TGFF as a identifier/variable based text file)

```
@TASK_GRAPH 0 {
PERIOD 1100

TASK t0_0   TYPE 13 
TASK t0_1   TYPE 3 
TASK t0_2   TYPE 10 
    .
    .

ARC a0_0    FROM t0_0  TO  t0_1 TYPE 9
ARC a0_1    FROM t0_1  TO  t0_2 TYPE 0
ARC a0_2    FROM t0_2  TO  t0_3 TYPE 37
    .
    .
}

#------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# type    exec_time
  0      71.659
  1     59.3856
  2     64.7101
```

this is as far as iv gotten so far (dont mind the fragmented code... this is just an example how iv done so far)

```
void read(char* graph){
     //open task graph description
     string name;
     string TaskList[300][300];
     ifstream gfile;
     gfile.open (graph);
     if ( !gfile.is_open() ) cout<<"Could not open graph description file\n";
     //start parsing
     while(getline(gfile,inptext)){
        istringstream sstream(inptext);
        int i=0;
        sstream >> name;
        if(name.compare("TASK")==0){
            sstream >> name;i
            //wrte node name to hash index i++
            sstream >> name;
            if (name.compare("TYPE")==0){
                sstream >> name;
                //retrieve node index from hash
                //write node weight to matrix
            }
        }
        if(name.compare("ARC")==0){
           sstream >> name;
           //write edge name to hash index i++
           sstream >> name;
           if (name.compare("FROM")==0){
              sstream >> name;
              //retrieve node index a from hash
           }
            sstream >> name;
            if (name.compare("TO")==0){
              sstream >> name;
              //retrieve node index b from hash
              if (name.compare("TYPE")==0){
                sstream >> name;
                //write edge weight to matrix index a b
              }
            }
         }
        i++;
     }
     //end parsing
     gfile.close();
 }
```

As I have not worked with tokens before I didn't bother reading up on them. Now the problem I encountered is the read cycle for `TYPE` values from the bottom of the file as their identifiers are regular numbers and you cant make them identifiers to search for. I'm guessing the best method would be to look for "# type" but as I'm using string stream it a bit harder to cope with. The second problem is that the number of nodes is unknown beforehand so I cannot initialize the array matrix to fit the size of the graph...

should I:

- a) read through the file twice - once to count nodes, other time to actually read the data
- b) use vector/matrix types(that I haven't used before and I reckon I'd have to build a matrix class to)
- c) use something else

The matrix I'm thinking of should be 
matrix[x][x] where n is the node weight and e is the edge weight (unmirrored since edges only go one way) so far i planned to populate the matrix with type numbers and read the types from a hash or vector later and replace them with the correct values

```
  A B C D E
A n 0 0 0 0
B e n 0 0 0
C e e n 0 0
D e e e n 0
E e e e e n
```

If anyone knows how to read and parse this file more easily it would be great.

Answer (score 1):

For addressing the problem of mapping task names to identifiers eg Mapping `t0_0` to 0,
`t0_1` to 1 as well as handling other formats for node names, I would recommend a hashtable with task name as the key and matrix index as the value.

The function below will return the index given the task name. If the task name is met for the first time, it will create a new index, assign it to the task name and return that.

```
#include <unordered_map>
int tasks = 0;
std::unordered_map<std::string, int> hashNameToIndex;

int nameToIndex(string name){    
  if (hashNameToIndex.find(name) == hashNameToIndex.end()){
     hashNameToIndex[name] = tasks;
     tasks++;
     return tasks-1;
  }else{
     return hashNameToIndex[name];
  }
}
```

Comment: a nice suggestion, been using the djb2 method for hash so far, any ideas on how to parse the type values though?

Comment: i don't understand what do you mean by "parse type values"

Comment: the file example i posted above has TYPE value marked for each TASK and ARC.... now the actual weights/values of these types are marked in a list at the bottom of the file such that "0      71.659" means type 0 with value 71.659. I need to replace these type identifiers with their respective values.... how would i go about parsing these values as the type identifiers are regular integer numbers?

Comment: make the matrix double. as a first step put as the elements of the matrix the type. When you have built the matrix, start reading the values for each type put them in an array eg. typevalues[type]=value. after you read all the values, for each element of the matrix, `matrix[r][c] = typevalues[(int)matrix[r][c]]`